# Solving a non-linear equation on python

Tags: python, math, sympy, nonlinear-optimization

i have been trying to solve a non-linear equation for a mechanical system but i couldn't find a way to do it properly.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import scipy.optimize as opt

a = 0.15
b = 0.4
c = 0.5
d = 0.4
e = 0.3
f = 0.35
beta = 0.3
qDot = 30
q = 0


def eqsSympy():
    teta3 = Symbol('teta3',real=True)
    teta4 = Symbol('teta4',real=True)
    teta5 = Symbol('teta5',real=True)
    s = Symbol('s',real=True)

    e1 = Eq(a*cos(q)+b*cos(teta3)-c*cos(teta4)-d)
    e2 = Eq(a*sin(q)+b*sin(teta3)-c*sin(teta4))
    e3 = Eq(e*cos(teta4-beta)+f*cos(teta5))
    e4 = Eq(e*sin(teta4-beta)+f*sin(teta5)-s)

    print(solve([e1,e2,e3,e4],teta3,teta4,teta5,s))
eqsSympy()
```

So i want these equations to be solved for values of q from 0 to 2*pi with pi/6 increments each step. But i keep getting the error :

> ```
> e1 = Eq(a*cos(q)+b*cos(teta3)-c*cos(teta4)-d)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Add' and 'function'
> ```

And also if there is a better way to solve these equations i'd appreciate if you help me.

Comment: I do not get any error when I run your code. I get the result `[(1.70873332321328, 2.22685691771982, 1.26737517209166, 0.615195151098434), (1.70873332321328, 2.22685691771982, 5.01581013508792, -0.0528287648918738), (4.57445198396631, -2.22685691771982, 0.795087655105900, 0.0768509475395103), (4.57445198396631, -2.22685691771982, 5.48809765207369, -0.422896542469970)]`. I use Python 3.7.1 and sympy version 1.3, running in the IPython 7.2.0 console in Spyder 3.3.2 running on Windows. 10.

Comment: Please show us the complete traceback that you get for the code that you show. It might also help if you state your version of Python and of sympy. If the error does not arise from the code you show, show the code that does cause the error. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, be careful with numpy and scipy here. The code shown here doesn't use them, but I can imagine this error was caused by using e.g. `np.sin` instead of `sympy.sin`